# При создании кастомного SimpleAdapter перестаёт нормально работать Фильтр

Tags: android, java, adapter

Я написал маленький код для кастомного SimpleAdapter (Просто расширил его,чтобы можно было использовать пользовательские шрифты). Дело в том,что мне потом необходимо в списке фильтровать данные,для этого необходимо получить экземпляр объекта Filter от адаптера методом `myadapter.getFilter().filter(x)`. В х Мы записываем символы, или слово, или буквы, по которым хотим произвести фильтрацию, тем самым изменяя содержимое ListView.

Проблема состоит в том, что если использовать обычный SimpleAdapter, то проблем никаких нету, и всё работает, как надо, а вот с моим адаптером такое не прокатило: поиск производится вообще не пойми как, абсолютно неверно. Подскажите,может знает кто,что делать?

Comment: В кастомном адаптере нужно фильтрацию переопределять тоже...

Comment: может использовать `ArrayAdapter` например?
у меня тоже как-то `симпл` не хотел работать, как надо